# How to listen for URL changes in a web-extension that are initiated in the web-app itself?

Tags: firefox-addon-webextensions

In a web-extension, I'm registering a content-script programmatically:

```
browser.contentScripts.register({
    matches: ["https://www.example.com/messages/*"],
    js: [{file: "my-callback-script"}],
    runAt: "document_idle"
});
```

The page I register it for changes its own URL without a page reload. No, not the bit right of the #, the bit of the URL to the left of the #, but still on the same domain/app. I don't think that web-extensions have a specific API for callbacks for URL changes, only for full page loads. The URL mask 'https://www.example.com/messages/*' is true for before and after, and I was hoping it would just work but it does not.

I'm pretty sure that `window.onhashchange` is not what I want, and `window.addEventListener('popstate', listener);` doesn't appear to be it either. How do I do this without polling every few seconds?

Comment: Have you tried to use browser.tabs.onUpdated? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/onUpdated

Comment: ever figure this out? i know it is old. i have the exact same situation as you.

Comment: no, never figured it out